# Currency format for EditText

Tags: android, input-mask

I am using this [library](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android) to format the text as user is typing. I have an `EditText` where user types in money. I want to achieve the following behavior as user types:

User input  ->  Result in `EditText`

1           ->  1 dollars

10          ->  10 dollars

100         ->  100 dollars

1000        ->  1 000 dollars

However, what I got is that:

1           ->  1 dollars

10          ->  10 dollars

100         ->  100 dollars

1000        ->  100 0 dollars

```
  val mask = MaskedTextChangedListener(
            "[000] [000] [000] dollars",
            false,
            etAmount,
            object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) { }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
            },
            null
        )

 etAmount.addTextChangedListener(mask)
```

The documentation is not very clear on how to achieve this and I am stuck on this issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this it might be helpful
https://github.com/CottaCush/CurrencyEditText

Comment: why do you have the regex tag on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Library author here.

We've got a [wiki page](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android/wiki/2.2-Right-to-Left-&-Digit-Grouping) describing masks for texts with right-to-left alignment; this page includes a case similar to yours.

In short, try configuring your listener like this:

```
mask.rightToLeft = true
```

Comment: My problem was that my listener's `rightToLeft` property was not getting recognized. Then after hours of investigation I found out that I was using the older version of the lib which is very silly I totally forgot about update my dependancies. Then, my `rightToLeft` started to get recognized by IDE. Thank you for the library and the for the hint!.